# How to make list from two or more arrays in C# using LinQ?

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

I have two string say `cityIds` and `cityNames`.

```
cityIds="1,2,3"
cityNames="Pune,Mumbai,Surat"
```

I have one class say `City.cs`

```
public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

From `cityIds` and `cityNames` I want to create List.

So if I have **Input** like this

```
cityIds="1,2,3"
cityNames="Pune,Mumbai,Surat"
```

I want **output** like this

```
list[0]=CityId=1,CityName="Pune"
list[1]=CityId=2,CityName="Mumbai"
list[2]=CityId=3,CityName="Surat"
```

I tried this

```
var listOfIds = cityIds.Split(',');
var listOfNames = cityNames.Split(',');
for(int i = 0; i < listOfIds.Count; i++)
{
     listOfDealerCities.Add(new City()
     {
          CityId = Int32.Parse(listOfIds[i]),
          CityName = listOfNames[i]
     });
}
```

Is there any better way to do this like using LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<City> listOfDealerCities = listOfIds.Select<string, City>(
(t, i) => new City()
{
    CityId = Int32.Parse(t),
    CityName = listOfNames[i]
})
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq's Zip method for this:

```
listOfDealerCities.AddRange(listOfIds.Zip(
listOfNames, (id, name) => new City() 
{
    CityId = int.Parse(id), CityName = name 
}));
```